# users images load realname or hide real name of image? image security

Tags: php, image, security, upload

i build a security script (not upload viruses s.e.) to upload images. I have now a question due to security of output the images on website.

Why this is not a security way to output the image:

```
<img src="/pathdir/imagerealname.jpg">
```

Why its better to make a script like photo.php and load original image as other name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL that you use for your image isn't a problem.  You can use whatever you want.  The issue comes when you allow users to store files on disk that they name.

While it is possible to allow a user to upload a file directly to something like `/users/username.jpg`, you must take extra caution to ensure that they don't set up their naming in such a way that the file lands in the wrong place, or becomes executable.

For example, maybe someone's username is `../../../etc/init.d/somethingevil`.  You wouldn't want them putting scripts there.  Or, maybe someone's username becomes `evil.php`, and then they can just call `/users/evil.php` and execute code on your servers.

Again, it is *possible* to set the file name to something the user provided, but then you have to do a bunch of checking to ensure it's fine.

There are also issues of usernames changing.  You would need to protect against someone changing to a username that someone else previously had.

Now, back to your PHP script.  What you could do is always write files to the hash of the username.  For example, on disk you might have `/var/www/images/users/B858CB282617FB0956D960215C8E84D1CCF909C6.jpg`.  And, you might have a rewrite rule that sets up all requests for `/images/users/(.*)` to go to `/user-image.php`.  `/user-image.php` then hashes this username and actually outputs the contents of the image on disk.  This also enables you to do things in your PHP script like resize that user image on-demand, via libvips or similar.